# Magento 2.1 Backend and Frontend "Please read Magento System Requirements."

Tags: magento2, upgrade, php-7

I've just upgraded from **Magento 2.0.7 CE** to **Magento 2.1.0 CE** on an Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS server. After installing PHP 7.0.11 and MySQL 5.6.30, as well as enabling PHP 7 using: *sudo a2enmod php7.0* via the command line.

PHPmyadmin is still working fine, as is the database connection. The issue is Magentos front/backend which reads "Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read Magento System Requirements."

I am unaware of any issues with PHP 7.0.11, so I'm not fully sure why it's not working. I upgraded using Composer, and installed the nescessary PHP 7 specific packages before I was able to install the upgrade.

I have checked /var/log/apache2/error.log, /var/log/mysql/error.log, /var/log/system.log and /var/log/exception.log (Was a new file).

Nothing seems out of the ordinary apart from being unable to access my Magento 2.1 frontend. I have restarted apache2 as well as rebooting the whole server with no success. Have I missed any information out to cause this issue?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you confirm that apache uses the right PHP version? Magento checks it using the `PHP_VERSION_ID` constant, so if you create a file with `<?php echo PHP_VERSION_ID;` and open it in the browser, you should see `70011`

Comment: @fschmengler I tried to open the file after creating it, even after giving it 755 and respective Chmod permissions with no luck. Somehow it's sorted but unfortunately I have no idea what I changed